# Ionic viewchild variable not available in ng-switch

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Am learning ionic however with the following code

```
@ViewChild(MultiImageUploadComponent) multiImageUpload: MultiImageUploadComponent;
```

however when i try to implement tabs using ion-segment and ng-switch i cant seen to access multiImageUpload from the second tab. like so . i keep getting the error co.multiImageUpload is undefined whenever switching to the second tab

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="defaultTab">
    <ion-segment-button value="managePhotos">
        Manage Photos
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="addPhotos">
        Add Photos
    </ion-segment-button>

  </ion-segment>
  <div [(ngSwitch)]="defaultTab">
        <ion-grid *ngSwitchCase="'managePhotos'">
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3 *ngFor="let photo of storyData.photos">
              <div class="image-container" [style.background-image]="'url('')'" (click)='photo()'></div>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
        <ion-grid *ngSwitchCase="'addPhotos'">
            <ion-row>
                <multi-image-upload></multi-image-upload>
                <button ion-button block (click)="newStory()" *ngIf="!multiImageUpload.isUploading && !uploadFinished">
                    <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
                    Upload
                </button>
                <button ion-button block (click)="cancel()" color="danger" *ngIf="multiImageUpload.isUploading && !uploadFinished">
                    <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
                    Cancel
                </button>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try putting #id and access the component by id

Comment: do you mean in the `addPhotos` segment you are not able to access the component?

Comment: Yes on the addPhotos section